# Printing compile-time integer sequence in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, sequence, variadic-templates, variadic

So I'm doing a bit of homework where I have to write my own compile-time integer sequence in C++11 and write a few functions for it (print, concat, sort etc.) but I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how I would go about writing these things.

```
template<typename T, typename Comp = std::less<int>>
struct Facility{

    template<T ... Nums>
    struct List{

        struct Element<T ... nums>{};

        template<unsigned num, T val, T ... rest>
        struct Element{
            unsigned index = num;
            T value = val;
            Element<index-1, rest...> others;
        };

        template<unsigned num, T val, T ... rest>
        struct Element<0, val>{
            unsigned index = 0;
            T value = val;
        };

        static constexpr Element<sizeof...(Nums)-1,Nums...> elem = {};

        static void Print()
        {
            // Prints out the list
        }
    };

};

using IntList = typename Facility<int>::List<intlist...>;

int main()
{
    using List1 = IntList<1, 2, 3>;
    List1::print()
}
```

I'd just like to know if I'm on the right track so I don't work myself into a dead end. I'm not 100% sure on the `static print()` and the `static constexpr` member in `List`, though I can't think of any other way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't clear to me what exactly do you want obtain and the meaning of what you have done (why `Facility`? why `List` inside facility?).

I just give you an example of how to write `Print()` without recursion, using an unused array (and defining `IntList`, as suggested by Yakk, taking inspiration from `std::integer_sequence`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, T ... Nums>
struct IntList
 {
   static void Print (std::ostream & s = std::cout)
    {
      using unused = int[];
      (void)unused { 0, ((void)(s << Nums << ", "), 0)... };
      s << std::endl;
    }
 };

int main()
 {
   using List1 = IntList<int, 1, 2, 3>;
   List1::Print();
 }
```

If you can use C++17 instead of C++11/C++14, you can write `Print()` without the unused hack, simply unpacking `Nums` as follows

```
   static void Print (std::ostream & s = std::cout)
    { (s << ... << (s << Nums, ", ")) << std::endl; }
```

Regarding concat and sort, I suppose you want member function that return (by example, the concat) a `IntList` with a concatenation of the two lists of numbers.

The a simple concat example can be the following static member for `IntList`

```
template <T ... Nums2>
static constexpr IntList<T, Nums..., Nums2...>
   Concat (IntList<T, Nums2...> const &)
 { return {}; }
```

So you can write something like

```
constexpr IntList<int, 1, 2, 3> l1;
constexpr IntList<int, 4, 5, 6> l2;

constexpr auto l3 = l1.Concat(l2);

l3.Print(); // print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```

I leave you the sort function as simple exercise :-)

Comment: Both Facility and List were provided in the assignment brief. Functions like sort etc. are to be provided in Facility, while Print is the only function inside List.

I realised a lot of my problem came from thinking that the List was an actual object, whereas I should have been thinking of it as a bunch of chained meta-function-created structs. I think I should be fine going forward from here. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

Don't needlessly nest types like that.  Write a `<T,Ts...>` sequence.

Don't couple operations to the type.  Write operations (tail, head) externally.

Take inspiration from `std::integer_sequence<T,T...>` in C++14.

If you need to have that interface you descrive in the OP, write it in terms of a flat one instead.

By far the easiest sort to write is merge sort.

Exploit `std::integral_constant`, which is C++11.  Write a metafunction that takes a template template parameter and one of your integer lists, and passes each integral constant to *as a type*, and generates a type list `template<class...Ts>struct types{};` as output.  Call this `foreach_int`

Write foreach_type, which takes a type list and invokes a function object on each element.  Now print is trivial; `template<class list> void print_list(){ foreach_type( foreach_int< idenitity, list >{}, print{} ); }` where `template<cls T> void print(T && t}{std::cout<<t;}`

Each of these is easier to reason about, and composing them gets you "print each".

But maybe I'm a bit nuts.

Comment: Sorry, to be totally honest I'm having trouble understanding most of that.

When you say needlessly nesting types, do you mean Facility & List? If so, those were both provided as part of the assignment code.

What do you mean by coupling operations to the type?

And to clarify, by flat, do you mean non-recursive? Like chaining inheritance in tuples?